# How to use NSUserDefaults in phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am new to this iOS/phonegap technology.
I am working on an iPhone/iOS app using phonegap. It has a login page with two text fields "Username" & "Password".

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg user_name" id="txtUserName" placeholder="Username" />
                    <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg pass_word" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" />
                    <button id="btnLogin" class="large color blue button login_top btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">Login</button>
```

On `$(document).ready(function()` Login processing is carried out.

Now I want to save email address of the user. i.e When I logged out it should remember the email address so it doesn't have to be input again.

I am developing this using phonegap. I went through many links and found out that this can be done using
1. NSUserDefaults
2. KeyChain

I am thinking of using NSUserDefaults, but am not understanding how to implement this thing.
i.e  Since this is native c code we have to write in the appDelegate.m file. Am I right?
And then how to link this code to my login page?

Can anyone please send me the full code to implement this functionality.
I mean the code that i need to add in appdelegate and linking that code to my login page.

Comment: use this plugin https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences for NSUserDefaults, or https://github.com/shazron/KeychainPlugin for KeyChain.

Answer (score 6):

If you or someone else needs it,
There is a cordova plugin for that:
    https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences/

```
cordova plugin add me.apla.cordova.app-preferences
```

Example from it's site:

```
var prefs = plugins.appPreferences;

// store key => value pair
prefs.store (ok, fail, 'key', 'value');

// store key => value pair in dict (see notes) 
prefs.store (ok, fail, 'dict', 'key', 'value');

// fetch value by key (value will be delivered through "ok" callback)
prefs.fetch (ok, fail, 'key');

// fetch value by key from dict (see notes)
prefs.fetch (ok, fail, 'dict', 'key');
```

Comment: For others coming to this post: This plugin is not compatible with cordova 9.0.0 and probably never will be, since the maintainer does not answer on issues and pull requests. However some forks exist that fix this issue.